# Calling Distance API from Tibco designer

Tags: web-services, ssl, https, tibco, mashape

I've tried to invoke a web service hosted on Mashape from my tibco design and i've received this error `Failed to create secure client socket: Server certificate rejected by ChainVerifier`

I've also tried solution posted by [nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039556/tibco-soap-request-over-https-ssl-certificate-verification-problem) but it didn't work.

[Link to webservice info](https://market.mashape.com/010pixel/distance)

Tibco designer console log: http://pastebin.com/iBhGHN4a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look at the certificate that Mashape is using you can see that it has also a Root and an intermediate certificate.

[image: screenshot]

You need to ensure you have all 3 of them in your trusted certificates folder.

Comment: By "trusted certificates folder", you mean the folder specified in the global variable right?

Comment: Yes, the one referenced by BW_GLOBAL_TRUSTED_CA_STORE, ensure also that the certificates are in a proper format (usually .cert)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error after doing what you suggested.

Comment: I've added my console log.